# How to unit test Slim framework applications

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, slim

I've been trying to unit test modifying examples of other peoples code and each time I get to the point my tests are running without errors - I just get the same failures when I expect them to pass. There isn't a great deal of documentation online, and I don't really know where else to go with this. Can anyone see where in my code I'm going wrong:

bootstrap.php (phpunit bootstrap file)

This is basically just a container for the $app object. I initiate the $app object with the same files I initiate my real application with (routes, config).

```
<?php
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname('../'));

// require composer autoloader for loading classes
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// app container class - singleton pattern
class App
{
     // Hold an instance of the class
    private static $instance;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            // Instantiate a Slim application:
            $app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
                'mode' => getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?: 'production',
            ));

            // set configuration
            require 'app/config.php';

            // include the routes (always after we've instantiated our app instance)
            require 'app/routes.php';

            self::$instance = $app;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Next, is my test file with one test:

AccountsControllerTest.php

```
<?php

use Slim\Environment;

class AccountsControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public static function get($path)
    {
        Environment::mock(array(
            'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
            'PATH_INFO' => $path,
        ));

        $app = App::getInstance();

        //$app->middleware[0]->call();
        $app->response()->finalize();
        return $app->response();
    }

    public function testIndex() {

        $response = $this->get('/accounts');

        $this->assertContains('Accounts', $response->getBody());
    }
}
```

Hopefully it's a little clear what I'm trying to do. Basically just check for the presence of "Accounts" (which, when I load in the browser, is present)

Below is the result I get back:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 4.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/shared-views-slim/phpunit.xml

F

Time: 33 ms, Memory: 4.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) AccountsControllerTest::testIndex
Failed asserting that '' contains "Accounts".

/var/www/shared-views-slim/tests/app/controllers/AccountsControllerTest.php:30

FAILURES!                            
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

**UPDATE:**

routes.php

```
<?php

// Define a HTTP GET route:
$app->group('/accounts', function () use ($app) {

    $controller = new App\Controllers\AccountsController($app);

    // index

    $app->get('/', function () use ($controller) {
        $controller->index();
    });

    // show

    $app->get('/:id', function ($id) use ($controller) {
        $controller->show($id);
    })->conditions(array('id' => '[1-9]([0-9]*)'));

    // create

    // form
    $app->get('/create', function () use ($controller) {
        $controller->create();
    });    

    // action
    $app->post('/', function () use ($controller) {
        $controller->create();
    });

    // update

    // form
    $app->get('/:id/edit', function ($id) use ($controller) {
        $controller->update($id);
    })->conditions(array('id' => '[1-9]([0-9]*)')); 

    // action
    $app->put('/:id', function ($id) use ($controller) {
        $controller->update($id);
    });

    // delete

    // form
    $app->get('/:id/delete', function ($id) use ($controller) {
        $controller->delete($id);
    })->conditions(array('id' => '[1-9]([0-9]*)')); 

    //action
    $app->delete('/:id', function ($id) use ($controller) {
        $controller->delete($id);
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Slim (though it looks great), would calling `finalize()` on the `Response` object cause `getBody()` to return an empty string?

Comment: Me too :) I just got started on it yesterday but really impressed with it. Actually I copied that in from someone elses code, I'm not sure why it's there. According to the documentation finalize returns an array with the body, status and header. If I comment it out just the same.

Comment: Well, the only other thing I can think of is the route from `app/routes.php` misbehaving. Would you be able to copy any of that code into the OP?

Comment: Hi. I've included the routes.php file (see update)

Comment: Falling deeper into the rabbit's hole, the controller's `index` function is closer to the issue, but I don't have its definition. In these cases, I usually apply `var_dump` liberally down the chain until I spot the issue.

Comment: Can you include the `App\Controllers\AccountsController` class file?

Comment: I'm the author of https://github.com/there4/slim-unit-testing-example. You may find it helpful. It uses a couple of helpers from https://github.com/there4/slim-test-helpers to establish a testing environment for Slim.