# PHP: Unit Test For My API

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, travis-ci

I created an API using SlimeFramework then wrote test to see if results returned from the routes are accurate and also  to test side effects of accessing these routes. I am making the client call with guzzle.

I am required to use continuous integration to send the information to travisCI, but travis does not have a host on which I can test my API, and guzzle requires a client(url) from which to make the route calls.

I am new to using any form of continuous integration and do not know what to do. I need help.

How do I test my API on travis?

Comment: what is SlimeFramework? Did you mean Slim? Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570614/how-to-unit-test-slim-framework-applications help?

Comment: yea, slime is what I meant