# PHP: How to test my REST API

Tags: php, heroku, phpunit, travis-ci, coveralls

I created a API and would like to test it. My initial thoughts was to use an API client, which I did, I used `guzzlehttp`, but after deploying the app to heroku and using travis and coveralls to build my test, it turns out coveralls is not able to see the part of my code covered by the test.

So my question is really "How do I test my REST API without an API Client?"
below is the link to my [Github](https://github.com/andela-gjames/Emoji-API/tree/develop) showing 0% as my test coverage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Unit Test For My API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704715/php-unit-test-for-my-api)